# Relation between two models with intermediate table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

have spent hours on trying and failing, reading the documentation and trying to translate the documentation to a challenge I am facing in Laravel.

The worst part is, I don't think the issue is that hard to solve, but somehow my head won't work properly.

The Laravel app I am working is a Tour de France Fantasy Manager. I have `Rider` and `Stage` models, and I have an intermediate `RiderStageStatus` model where I will store information about whether a rider is joining the stage. I want to implement stage results as well, so I guess the issue will turn up again for that later on.

However, my database looks like this:

```
riders
- id
- name
- ...

stages
- id
- departure
- arrival
- ...

statuses
- id
- name
- ...

rider_stage_statuses
- id
- rider_id
- stage_id
- status_id
```

So I should be able to get riders and their status for a certain stage `Stage::find(1)->riders` and also get statuses for each stage of a rider `Rider::find(1)->stages`.

But I cannot make the right relations in the models. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rider_stage_statuses` looks like the pivot table of a ternary relationship. Laravel does not support those so having `RiderStageStatus` is probably inevidable. I'd argue that in your particular case a ternary is not strictly necessary but if you still want to go down that path prepare for additional challanges

Comment: @apokryfos Interesting, I would preferably to the smartest thing in the long run. How should I get started if I should avoid a ternary relationship?

Comment: Well personally I'm looking at the `status` table suspiciously. It really depends on what your data model is but I would expect the status to be directly related to a rider rather than a rider/stage assuming I have understood what the status is correctly.

Comment: @apokryfos I understand. The issue is that a rider might drop out of one stage because of injury. But he will be attending the next stage. Thus I need to add a status per stage per rider.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) shows you can add an extra argument to tell Laravel what table to use as pivot table.

Build your classes as follows:

#### Class rider

```php
class Rider {

    public function stages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stage::class, 'rider_stage_statuses');
    }
}
```

#### Class stage

```php
class Stage {
    
    public function riders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rider::class, 'rider_stage_statuses');
    }
}
```

## Solution 2

We could also fix your code by fixing the [intermediate table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

Whe should structure your code like this:

#### Class rider

```php
class Rider {

    public function stages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stage::class)->using(RiderStageStatus::class);
    }
}
```

#### Class stage

```php
class Stage {
    
    public function riders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rider::class)->using(RiderStageStatus::class);
    }
}
```